# What do you call this kind of cable?

Tags: connector, cables

I'm planning on building a board with a bunch of logic gates on to experiment with. I'm looking for a kind of cable that I've seen before but don't know the name of. It basically connects to a solid pin, and is stackable (see attached picture). What is the name of such cables?

Thanks.

[image]

Edit like:
[image]

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/products/en/test-and-measurement/test-leads-banana-meter-interface/627

Answer (score 9):

In a catalogue, look for 4 mm plugs. In daily life, they're known as banana plugs.

The 4 mm plugs you show are stackable but they also come in plain male plugs. Check when ordering that you have the stackable ones.

Comment: Nice summary. Although 4mm is the common size, it's worth noting that a 2mm version of banana plugs & sockets is also available (e.g. ["Hirschmann 973595100 Test Lead, 2mm Banana Plug to 2mm Banana Plug"](http://uk.farnell.com/hirschmann-testmeasurement/973595100/test-lead-blk-500mm-60v-6a/dp/523598) from Farnell, just as an example), which I've seen used for low currents when space is limited.

Answer (score 7):

The most common term I've seen for this type of connector is "(stackable) banana plugs". They're frequently used for home stereo speakers as well as for test equipment.

Answer (score 1):

From drawing, that's cables with "stackable" banana plug, probably 4mm (0.16 in). Note, that there are several  variants of 4mm ones, that differ by length. If that's 2mm (can't tell without scale on photo) , there is only one kind widely known.

Answer (score -1):

this type of cable are commonly called **jumper cables**. I have used them many times for prototyping a circuit with bread board.

Comment: These are jumper cables: https://www.google.com/search?q=jumper+cables&tbm=isch

Comment: That are jumper cables for car. These are also called jumper cables. Here is a link @pipe : https://www.google.co.in/search?q=jumper+cables&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9t6qsy9rTAhVLLo8KHVQbDvkQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=950#tbm=isch&q=jumper+cables+arduino

Comment: `jumper cables arduino` shows me [this](https://cdn.instructables.com/FGF/QB07/HX7P7I3J/FGFQB07HX7P7I3J.MEDIUM.jpg) type, meant for breadboards. Not what the user asks about.

Comment: @pipe actually , I agree. In general such cables called jumper cables or, but it is general term, that doesn't refer to connectors used, it's purpose of the cable. This particular kind of jumpers often called "banana plugs". Association with car `booster cables` is due to term `jump start`, which also gives them name `jump leads`. Usually jumper got a "crocodile" clamp on one side and "banana" on other, but "banana-to-banana" exists too